# Нужно переходить по ссылкам,собирать данные,а после выходить назад и по новой

Tags: python

К примеру страничка днса с покупкой микроволновок: https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/17a8c89d16404e77/mikrovolnovye-pechi/

Я не понимаю как мне по порядку спарсить все данные о микроволновках. Т.е надо как-то заставить скрипт перейти на страничку, собрать все данные, выйти назад и перейти уже на следующую микроволновку.

3 дня с этим бьюсь, помогите ;(

Comment: А как Вы уже пробовали решать задачу, тем более раз бьётесь над ней уже 3 дня?

Comment: Я с селениумом пытался что-то вытворить,но как только надо было переходить к следующей 'микроволновке' то весь процесс вставал и я пытался переписать код полностью. Это ничего полезного так и не дало, максимум потерянные нервные клетки

Comment: клик по кнопке "переход назад" для драйвера - .back()

Comment: А не знаете как мне сделать переход на карточку ниже?

Comment: так же, как кликнули по первой )) кликали на какой-нибуть a class="ui-link" href="product/c2a9da46ce083332", он был первым в списке, теперь - во второй и т.д.